# Define $\varphi_a:F\to\Bbb R$ by $\varphi_a(f)=f(a)$ for $f\in F$, then $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is a ring homomorphism for each $a\in\Bbb R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Below is a proof I've written to show a ring homomorphism. This is how I was taught to write them, with the proposition, then the proof. So if it's redundant, I'm sorry. What I'm asking is whether or not my proof is accurate? Does it need more? Did I make incorrect assumptions?

Proposition: Let $F$ be the ring of functions $f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$, and consider the usual ring of real numbers $\Bbb R$. Define the map $\varphi_a:F\rightarrow \Bbb R$ by $\varphi_a(f)=f(a)$ for $f \in F$, then $\varphi_a: F \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is a ring homomorphism for each $a \in \Bbb R$.

Proof: Let $F$ be the ring of functions $f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$, and consider the usual ring of real numbers $\Bbb R$. Define the map $\varphi_a:F\rightarrow \Bbb R$ by $\varphi_a(f)=f(a)$ for $f \in F$. Let $g \in F$ such that $\varphi_a(g)=g(a)$.

Step 1: We want to show that $\varphi_a(f+g)=\varphi_a(f)+\varphi_a(g)$.

$\varphi_a(fg)=f+g(a)$

$=f(a)+g(a)$

$=\varphi_a(f)+\varphi_a(g)$

Thus, we have shown $\varphi_a(f+g)=\varphi_a(f)+\varphi_a(g)$.

Step 2: We want to show that $\varphi_a(fg)=\varphi_a(f)\varphi_a(g)$.

$\varphi_a(fg)=fg(a)$

$=f(a)g(a)$

$=\varphi_a(f)\varphi_a(g)$

Thus, $\varphi_a(fg)=\varphi_a(f)\varphi_a(g)$.

Hence, by steps 1 and 2 we have shown that $\varphi_a:F\rightarrow \Bbb R$ is a ring homomorphism for each $a \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: What are your axioms for a ring homomorphism? First, $\phi_a(f+g)=\phi_a(f)+\phi_a(g)$, secondly $\phi_a(fg)=\phi_a(f)\phi_a(g)$ etc? Then your proof is not yet complete, and also $\phi(f)$ and $\phi(g)$ are not defined in your computation (you haven't defined $\phi$, only $\phi_a$). And is $\phi_a$ mapping the unit element of $F$ to the one of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you. I had realized I left off the addition, I just hadn't edited the post to correct for that yet. However, I would have done that in a similar fashion to how I did the multiplication. I was concerned about the lack of a definition of φ
 though. The original problem asked us to either prove it was a ring homomorphism or give a counter example. I used all the information we were given. The lack of a definition for $\varphi$ should have given me more pause. Would this mean I can create a definition for it that would create a counterexample?

Comment: I wanted to say that you made a "mistake" by writing $f(a)=g(a)=\phi(f)\phi(g)$. There is no $\phi$. You need $\phi_a$. Secondly, did you check your definition of a ring gomormophism $f\colon R\rightarrow S$? Does it require $f(1_R)=1_S$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Our definition of homomorphism is just $\varphi(a+b)=\varphi(a)+\varphi(b)$ and $\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$. It doesn't mention anything about $f(1_R)=1_S$. In my handwritten copy I did put $=\varphi_a(f)\varphi_a(g)$, I just mistyped it when I typed it up above. I'll correct that. As well as add in the addition portion of the proof.

Comment: For commutative rings we also require $f(1_R)=1_S$, so $f(id)=1$. However, $\phi_a(id)=1_{\Bbb R}=1$ says that $a=id(a)=1$, so $a=1$. This is a contradiction for all other $a$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde it seems like you're saying that $a=1$ is a counterexample proving that this isn't a ring homomorphism. To be clear, I never had to prove it was a commutative ring, just that it was a ring homomorphism.

Comment: Oh, both rings $F$ and $\Bbb R$ are commutative, right?

Comment: @DietrichBurde it's not stated outright. It's only said to "consider the usual ring of real numbers $\Bbb R$ which would imply that $\Bbb R$ is. There is no mention in the question about $F$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank you for your help. My professor looked at the proof and said it was fine.